# Sorting multiple LINQ results of different models as one list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I am trying to sort a list of users that are either students, colleagues or guests and sort them in my view based on their names.

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new PraktikumDataContext();
            var model = new List<AdminUserListItem>();
            var studs = (from stud in db.Students select new AdminUserListItem() {Name = stud.FH_Angehörige.Name, LastLogin = stud.FH_Angehörige.FE_Nutzer.Letzter_Login, Rolle = "Student"}).OrderBy(stud => stud.Name);
            model.AddRange(studs);
            var mits = (from mit in db.Mitarbeiters select new AdminUserListItem() {Name = mit.FH_Angehörige.Name, LastLogin = mit.FH_Angehörige.FE_Nutzer.Letzter_Login, Rolle = "Mitarbeiter"}).OrderBy(stud => stud.Name);
            model.AddRange(mits);
            var gasts = (from gast in db.Gasts select new AdminUserListItem() {Name = gast.Name, LastLogin = gast.FE_Nutzer.Letzter_Login, Rolle = "Gast"}).OrderBy(stud => stud.Name);
            model.AddRange(gasts);

            model = model.OrderByDescending()
            return View(model);
        }
```

What I've already done with OrderBy sorts each model in it's own scope, however since I have 3 models, I am a little bit confused now how to somehow make them to be seen as one list and then sort them and show them in my website.

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem - is the current code not working? what is not working with it? (by the way, you shouldn't sort each time and then sort again - it's inefficient - sorting is more efficient when you have a regular spread of values)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a LINQ union that makes a single call to the server:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new PraktikumDataContext();

            var model = 
                 (from stud in db.Students
                  select new AdminUserListItem()
                  {
                    Name = stud.FH_Angehörige.Name, 
                    LastLogin = stud.FH_Angehörige.FE_Nutzer.Letzter_Login, 
                    Rolle = "Student"}
                  ).Union(
                  from mit in db.Mitarbeiters
                  select new AdminUserListItem()
                  {
                    Name = mit.FH_Angehörige.Name, 
                    LastLogin = mit.FH_Angehörige.FE_Nutzer.Letzter_Login, 
                    Rolle = "Mitarbeiter"}
                  ).Union(
                  from gast in db.Gasts
                  select new AdminUserListItem()
                  {
                    Name = gast.FH_Angehörige.Name, 
                    LastLogin = gast.FE_Nutzer.Letzter_Login, 
                    Rolle = "Gast"}
                  )
                  .OrderByDescending(a => a.Name)
                  .ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
```